# When creating a Minecraft server, do I have to use my Suddenlink modem/router provided by the ISP or can I use my secondary Nighthawk router?

Tags: server, minecraft

I have a modem/router that is provided by my ISP that is still in use, but I also have an additional Nighthawk router that I primarily connect to. I'm not sure if there is any issue with using the Nighthawk router as opposed to the modem/router. One piece of evidence that makes me think the Nighthawk is not designed to be used like that is that when I type in my default gateway into my internet browser, it says not safe, while the modem/router says that it's safe.

In short, can I use my Nighthawk router as my server's connection, or must I use the default modem/router provided by the ISP?

Answer (score 0):

It depends. If your Nighthawk is connected to your ISP's router and is not set up as an access point, and all your devices are connected to the Nighthawk, then you have a double NAT in place, meaning that within the local IP's of the ISP router, there is another subnet with more local IP's(the Nighthawk subnet). In order to properly portforward, the router should forward traffic directly to the local IP, which is not possible if the device is attached to another subnet. However, you could forward a port from the ISP router to the Nighthawk to your computer, but this may not work.

If your Nighthawk is configured as an access point it doesn't matter. You can connect the server to either router but you must set up port forwarding on the ISP router.

You have a few options if it is not configured as an access point.

1. Just configure it as an access point (pretty painless, saves time in the future)
2. Connect the server to the ISP router and portforward from there (also works, but your server cannot access other devices connected to the Nighthawk)
3. Do a double portforward from the ISP router to the Nighthawk, then from the Nighthawk to the server (may not work)
4. Use a vpn service such as [Hamachi](https://vpn.net) (may be slow)